# Symfony 1.4 routing issue

Tags: php, symfony1, symfony-1.4

I have symfony 1.4 application. On windows AMP all is right.
But on Linux Apache2 i have an isseu:

For example, i have deployed application on myhost.

http://myhost/ - works right,
but http://myhost/module - doesn't work.

But in i use frontend_dev.php - all is right.

http://myhost/frontend_dev.php/module/ - works.

Cache is clean.
And on Windows AMP - all is right.

A haven't any changes of .htaccess and in settins in apache.

Added:

I have the following configuration of .htaccess

Options +FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On

  # uncomment the following line, if you are having trouble
  # getting no_script_name to work
  RewriteBase /

  # we skip all files with .something
  #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \..+$
  #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.html$
  #RewriteRule .* - [L]

  # we check if the .html version is here (caching)
  RewriteRule ^$ index.html [QSA]
  RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.html [QSA]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

  # no, so we redirect to our front web controller
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is working like `url/index.php/module`, then you need to enable `mod_rewrite` for your vhost.

Comment: Thx, but it enabled in .htaccess

Comment: You need to enable it in your apache configuration to be able to use it in your .htaccess. Comment the <IfModule> lines in the .htaccess file, and if you get an internal server error, mod_rewrite is disabled.

Answer (score 1):

As Maerlyn has stated, this problem is usually due to the fact that you do not have mod_rewrite enabled.

The easiest way to enable mod_rewrite, is to add the following lines in your .htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
```

That should fix your routing problems.

Comment: He needs an AllowOverride directive, but I'm not sure, which. I usually end up using `AllowOverride All`.

Comment: Maerlyn: Thanks so much! I had a similar problem and `AllowOverride All` fixed it perfectly.

Comment: As another note, it appears that `AllowOverride FileInfo` is the crucial override which needs to be allowed for mod_rewrite to work properly.